# How to find a point in $R^n$ satisfying a set of nonlinear inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f_i: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ be a smooth map and $a_i \leq b_i$ for $i=1, \dots, m$. How can one find a point $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$ satisfying $a_i \leq f_i(x) \leq b_i$ for all $i$?

My current solution is to frame it as the following non-linear optimization problem: minimize $0$ subject to $a_i \leq f_i \leq b_i \forall i$. I'm then using a optimizer to find a solution. I'm untrained in optimization however, so I would prefer a more direct approach (if it exists) to the problem of finding $x$.

If optimization is the only solution then I would like to better understand how this method works. I understand the basic method of gradient descent, but how could such a method be applied when the objective function is constant? How do optimization problems find feasible solutions in these cases?

Edit: For my specific application, each $f_i$ is of the form $f_i(x) = x_a+x_b$ or $f_i(x)=x_a/x_b$.

Comment: Optimization techniques are very dependent upon the kinds of functions involved. What are the characteristics of your $f_i$? Are they convex?

Comment: "How do optimization problems find a feasible solution": there are various techniques to transform a feasibility problem into an optimization problem, and vice-versa. E.g. if the question is whether there exists $x$ such that $a \le f(x) \le b$, this is the same as minimizing $t + u$ where $z, t, u, v$ are all $\ge 0$ and $f(x) = a + z - t = b + u - v$.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni if any of the functions are nonlinear, as they are represented to be, those constraints will not be convex, because at least one side of each inequality will be going the wrong direction to be convex; the only exception being if the violating bound inequality is redundant and can be eliminated, such as a lower bound of zero on a nonnegative (convex) function.

Comment: You are right. Then if you only look for one solution, gradient descent is OK. Of course you need to minimize something, e.g. $\sum_i (f_i(x)-(a_i+b_i)/2)^2$. With simulated annealing if there are many local minima.

Comment: If however you need additional data, such as the number of disjoint zones where the problem is feasible, you may try finding some cuts (linear or not) that separate feasible regions of each $f_i$, take their intersection, and on each zone do a gradient descent.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni My specific application is very specific, each $f_i$ is of the form $f_i(x) = x_a+x_b$ or $f_i(x)=x_a/x_b$. Correct me if I'm wrong but the second form is non-convex I believe, is that bad news?

Comment: @Henry What are $x_a$ and $x_b$? Some coordinates of $x$? Some functions of $x$? As for the division, note that there are some specific results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_programming

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Yes they are coordinates $x = (x_1, ..., x_n), a,b \in [n]$.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I answered your comment but forgot to inform you, sorry.

Comment: @Henry Then your problem is equivalent to a Linear Programming problem, it seems. I will now write an answer.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moron If the denominators have fixed sign, you can just multiply both sides of the inequality by the denominator (reversing inequality direction if denominator is negative), and end up with a system of linear inequalities, which can be provided to a Linear Programming solver. If not, I don't think there is any equivalent Linear Programming problem.  Linear Fractional programming addresses fraction in objective function (having fixed-sign denominator)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be transformed into a LP (Linear Programming) problem:

- $a_i \le x_a + x_b \le b_i$ is equivalent to two linear constraints.
- $a_i \le x_a/x_b \le b_i$ is equivalent to $x_b \gt 0:  x_a - a_i x_b \ge 0, x_a - b_i x_b \le 0$, or $x_b < 0: x_a - a_i x_b \le 0, x_a - b_i x_b \ge 0$. So two branches with two linear constraints each.

To deal with the branches, you may make cases depending upon the signs of denominator variables, or transform it into $x_b (x_a - a_i x_b) \ge 0$ and $x_b (x_a - b_i x_b) \le 0$, which are quadratic constraints, although quite simple because the left hand-side is null.

To solve the system, you may use a solver that allows for quadratic constraints, or you may use a purely linear solver and have a case-based reasoning above it. If you prefer writing the program yourself, the simplex method is the easiest and one of the most efficient methods available for linear problems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Note that in your problem you just want to find a feasible solution (i.e. a point that satisfies all constraints), rather than an optimal solution, as there is nothing to be optimized. And on the other hand the simplex algorithm requires a feasible solution for its initialization.

In this case there is a phase 1 which consists in finding a feasible point (and you'll stop there, as phase 2 is to optmize the objective function). Phase 1 is solved by applying the simplex algorithm to a modified version of the problem. The idea is to add slack variables, so that there is a trivial solution, and to minimize the sum of those slack variables. So for example $x_a - a_i x_b \le 0$ is transformed into $x_a - a_i x_b + u = 0$, where $u$ is a slack variable. But a solver will manage all that, slack variables and phases, for you.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful